# Cobertura makes my unit test fail. How to solve it?

Tags: java, unit-testing, cobertura

I have a java class in a java project. I wrote 3 test cases for it with junit. The test cases are successful if I run them in Eclipse or mvn test in cmd. But every time I run them with mvn cobertura:cobertura, they all fail. However every other test case in the same project will pass.

Any suggestions? Or has someone seen this before?

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Any more information would be helpful. Most probably some initialization or config is missing. In what way do the tests fail?

Comment: Are the tests running in the same order?

Comment: Can you post some error message?